# What genre the group VersaEmerge plays?

Tags: genre

I really enjoy this band and their style of music. But there is no conrete information about the genre they play.

It has quite an electronic touch. But I can't say exactly.

The Wikipedia page and their official site have low information about this, and nothing really conclusive.

I know they used to play (some sort of) rock, but I'm more interested in the most recent stuff.

For reference, here are some videos:

- No Consequences:    https://youtu.be/-fK0igwZZh0
- Burn:    https://youtu.be/zZ_jGQNENQo
- Bones:    https://youtu.be/sbuIWryoHRw
- Domesticated:    https://youtu.be/In-IORil7G0

---

Outside the scope of this question, I would appreciate suggestions on bands that play the same style. Maybe CAZZETTE is somewhat close to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the video of the song "No Consequences", on [a comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fK0igwZZh0&lc=9r7a-c-NSn4mF-QD7ayY3_KLrgoJy5eznvq7ZjW9tRQ) in the comment section:

> [...]They've taken themselves from experimental pop to experimental rock[...]

The group has been around since 2009 under the name VersaEmerge but from what I have read most of the members left and only 2 remain.

They will be changing their name to VERSA and their new channel is officialversaband, and they're releasing an EP next month.

Search VERSA Neon to find the new song
OR
Find them here:

- https://www.youtube.com/user/OfficialVersaBand
- http://www.versa.fm
- http://www.facebook.com/VERSAband
- http://www.twitter.com/VERSA_band
- http://www.instagram.com/VERSAofficial

Some more prominent musicians:

- http://www.allmusic.com/style/experimental-rock-ma0000002583

Comment: Thank you! I have to search more about experimental rock. I was aware that they were changing name, but wasn't sure about which name it would be. This has so much valuable information! It almost brings me tears. I hope others appreciate your effort.

Comment: The only thing I'm having some problems is to find that citation, to add to the answer. It would be really great if you could link it. It's not required, it's not an order. It's just a request. I simply can't find the citation. Also, you should format the citation using `>[space]`. The links could be a simple list. A list is simply made with `[space]-[space]`. If you wish, I can clean up the formatting for you.

Comment: What Citation?? The information given was a collection taken from source (Video Comments Mostly)

Comment: "`Listen to the fans, "They've taken themselves from experimental pop to experimental rock"`" <-- That part.

Comment: 9th Comment on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fK0igwZZh0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Thank you. I've made an edit to try to improve the answer. You can pick up from there and change whatever you find appropriate. Once again, thank you a lot for the information. It really is extremelly valuable